# Tag links -- the [tag:some-tag] type -- seem to point to wacky places

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that my user profile on Meta, which was automatically copied over from my profile on Stack Overflow, have links that don't make sense (to me). (If I remember correctly, the first time I had changed my profile, I had selected the option to "Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts").

In my profile, which was written for Stack Overflow where I'm most active, I had linked to some of my favorite tags using the `[tag:blah-blah-blah]` construct, so they show up nicely formatted (example: [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)).

However, it seems like this creates tags relative to the Stack Exchange site that the profile is *displayed at*, not the one where the profile was *created*.

While writing this question itself, I also noticed that the tag in this question points to stackoverflow.com (not meta.stackoverflow.com!)

Is this behavior an oversight or a feature?

Also, since Meta doesn't seem to have an option to edit one's profile, for such links, shouldn't they be made to automatically point to the network site at which the profile (or question) was created?

Comment: The second point with the standard tag-links always pointing to the main site (Except for MSO where none exists) is **by-design**. The first one is probably just **happenstance**, at least I doubt anyone thought about it all that much.

Comment: @Deduplicator MSO now has a main site.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Damn. That should have been MSE in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This markdown is intended to be a convenience for individual sites. For tags on meta, you can also use `[meta-tag:blah]` to create a short link to a tag on meta.

For all other users (including profile), you're best off using normal hyperlinks. You can also edit your profile on each site to change up which tags you want to show off, if any.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the explanation. I guess I'll have to stop being lazy and actually customize my profiles across sites on the SE network.