# How to create links to tags on meta?

Tags: support, tags, meta, formatting

I was reading a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268917/2126755) and came across the tag: [daily-reputation-limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daily-reputation-limit). It links to an empty Stack Overflow page. I wanted to edit the post so that the it links to the [right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daily-reputation-limit), however I discovered I don't know how.

I tried the following markdown (and a few other things), but nothing worked.

```
[[tag:daily-reputation-limit]][3]
```

How can one use the `[tag:name]` syntax for tags specific to meta?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261921/1048572, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189337/183280, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69513/183280

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just figured it out

[daily-reputation-limit](/questions/tagged/daily-reputation-limit)

```
[meta-tag:daily-reputation-limit]
```